# Why are my estimated and theoretical results for sobol sensitivity analysis different?

Tags: r, analysis, variance

I am working on the sobol sensitivity analysis. I am trying to compute the first order effect and total effect indices in both an estimated and theoretical way.

Firstly, I computed the estimated values by following the steps in Wikipedia "Variance-based sensitivity analysis".

[image: These are the estimated equations]

Here is the code:

```
set.seed(123)

x_1<-ceiling(1000*runif(1000))  ## generate x1 from range [1,1000]
x_2<-ceiling(100*runif(1000))   ## generate x2 from range [1,100]
x_3<-ceiling(10*runif(1000))    ## generate x3 from range [1,10]
x<-cbind(x_1,x_2,x_3)           ## combine as one matrix

A<-matrix(x[1:500,],ncol=3)     ## divide this one matrix into two 
B<-matrix(x[501:1000,],ncol=3)  

AB1<-cbind(B[,1],A[,-1])        ## replace the first column of sample A by the first column of sample B
AB2<-cbind(A[,1],B[,2],A[,3])   ## replace the second column of sample A by the second column of sample B 
AB3<-cbind(A[,-3],B[,3])        ## replace the third column of sample A by the third column of sample B 

trial<-function(x){             ## define the trial function: 
    #x1+x2*x3^2 
    x[,1]+(x[,2])*(x[,3])^2
}

Y_A<-trial(A)                 ## the output of A
Y_B<-trial(B)                 ## the output of B

Y_AB1<-trial(AB1)             ## the output of AB1
Y_AB2<-trial(AB2)             ## the output of AB2
Y_AB3<-trial(AB3)             ## the output of AB3

Y<-matrix(cbind(Y_A,Y_B),ncol=1)  ## the matrix of total outputs

S1<-mean(Y_B*(Y_AB1-Y_A))/var(Y)    ## first order effect of x1 
St1<-(sum((Y_A-Y_AB1)^2)/(2*500))/var(Y) ## total order effect of x1

S2<-mean(Y_B*(Y_AB2-Y_A))/var(Y)     ## first order effect of x2
St2<-(sum((Y_A-Y_AB2)^2)/(2*500))/var(Y)  ## total order effect of x2

S3<-mean(Y_B*(Y_AB3-Y_A))/var(Y)     ## first order effect of x3
St3<-(sum((Y_A-Y_AB3)^2)/(2*500))/var(Y) ## total order effect of x3

S<-matrix(c(S1,St1,S2,St2,S3,St3),nrow=2,ncol=3)  ## define the results 
matrix

rownames(S)<-list("first order","total")
colnames(S)<-list("X1","X2","X3")
S                                               ## print result
```

The results are:

```
                    X1        X2        X3
first order 0.01734781 0.2337758 0.5261082
total       0.01523861 0.4078107 0.6471387
```

And then, I wanted to compute the theoretical results to validate the above estimated results. I follow the equations in the picture below:

[image]

In order to compute the partial variance, I approached it in two ways: monte carlo integration and doing the integration by hand ( I just don't trust computer...)

Here is the code:

```
pimc=function(n){                      ## monte carlo integration
a=runif(n)
  g=(a+mean(x_2)*(mean(x_3)^2))^2
  pimc=mean(g)
  pimc

}

pimc(10000)/var(Y)
                                                                  ## 
# doing integration by hand
(1/3+mean(x_2)*(mean(x_3))^2+((mean(x_2))^2)*((mean(x_3))^4))/var(Y)  
## first order effect x1
(mean(x_1)^2+mean(x_1)*mean(x_3)^2+(1/3)*mean(x_3)^4)/var(Y)          
## first order effect x2
(mean(x_1)^2+(2/3)*(mean(x_1)*mean(x_2))+(1/5)*(mean(x_2)^2))/var(Y)  
## first order effect x3
```

The results are the following:

```
       [,1]
[1,] 0.4414232        ## first order indice of x1 computed by monte carlo integration
        [,1]
[1,] 0.4414238          ## first order indice of x1 computed by hand
       [,1]
[1,] 0.0505044         ## first order indice of x2 computed by hand
       [,1]   
[1,] 0.05086958         ## first order indice of x3 computed by hand
```

The results are constant by using monte-carlo integration and hand solving. **But they are quite different from the estimated results**. Why is this?

When we do partial integral, we only look at one parameter, and we treat other parameters as constant numbers. So I chose to take the mean of each parameter as the constant number. Is it wrong?

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion about this?

Comment: This seems more appropriate for cross validated. There is no real programming question.

Comment: @Cole I think the programming part comes from a generalisable Monte Carlo integration method and/or by hand integration?